# Get video information using YouTubeThumbnailView

Tags: android, api, youtube

I'm using `YouTubeThumbnailView` to show a thumbnail of the video linked into my app.

I'm using that code:

```
youtube_thumb.initialize(getContext().getString(R.string.google_api_key), new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {

        youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(url);
        youtube_thumb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (YouTubeIntents.canResolvePlayVideoIntentWithOptions(getContext())) {
                    //Opens in the YouTube app in fullscreen and returns to this app once the video finishes
                    getContext().startActivity(YouTubeIntents.createPlayVideoIntentWithOptions(getContext(), url, true, true));
                }else{
                    getContext().startActivity(YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent((AppCompatActivity) getContext(), getContext().getString(R.string.google_api_key), url));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
        youtube_thumb.setVisibility(GONE);
    }
});
```

What I need now is to show video information such as title and description.

Is there a way to get that information in the `onInitializationSuccess` callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the info from the `YouTubeThumbnailView`, but you can use YouTube Data API, and do something like this using okhttp:
(check if it works, it's old code from when i was playing with youtube api)

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=");
builder.append(url)
       .append("&fields=items/snippet/title,items/snippet/description&key=")
       .append("API_KEY");
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(builder.toString()).build();
Response response = null;
response = client.newCall(request).execute();
if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
    //DO SOMETHING
}
JSONObject snippet=new JSONObject(response.body().string())
          .getJSONArray("items").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("snippet");
String title=snippet.getString("title");
String description=snippet.getString("description");
```